# sqlite database help

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have some questions regarding database in android.

1. In my project, I would like to create a database with single table. I would also like to insert data on this table from word or excel document. is it possible? if so please how can I do it? some code snippets would be of great help.
2. I have four different activities which I would like them to interact with this single table. the first is the main activity and its purpose is just to launch the other three activities according to user choice. so it has no interaction with the DB. but the other three activities will read from the table whenever called. Can you please tell me how to call the dbhelper on these activities? I am unable to do this and I am currently creating one db per each activity which is not the optimal way.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) on interacting with a database in Android, it is a complete sample application with explanations.

Comment: This tutorial is a great starting place and is a good reference for all "intro to working with a database in android" type questions.